# Yarn install - bad hash behind private registry - Jhipster v5 upgrade

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg

I report an issue with Yarn and the installation of Javascript dependencies from a Jhipster v4 to [Jhipser v5.0.1](https://www.jhipster.tech/2018/06/23/jhipster-release-5.0.1.html) (Angular stack) throug a private Nexus Npm proxy and private Artifactory registry

However, I am experiencing sha1sum errors when installing javascript dependencies with Yarn

Exemple :

```
> [INFO] [1/5] Validating package.json... 
> [INFO] [2/5] Resolving packages... 
> [INFO] [3/5] Fetching packages...
> [ERROR] error http://registry.npmjs.org/compression/-/compression-1.7.2.tgz: Fetch
> succeeded for undefined. However, extracting
> "http://registry.npmjs.org/compression/-/compression-1.7.2.tgz"
> resulted in hash "b0850fe39bd92980d49335a26b3deb4fcc71a64d", which did
> not match the requested hash "aaffbcd6aaf854b44ebb280353d5ad1651f59a69".
```

Sometimes it's with these libraries:

- follow-redirects-1.5.1
- onetime-1.1.0
- compression-1.7.2

With Node v8.9.4 or v8.11.3
Whether with Yarn 1.6.0, 1.7.0 or 1.8.0

I of course did that:

- Do a `yarn cache clean`
- Delete ***node_modules/***
- Remove ***yarn.lock***
- Add the Yarn flag ***--skip-integrity-check***

Whith an curl http://private-artifactory/compression/-/compression-1.7.2.tgz the sha1sum is OK
It's also OK with an direct internet access (without corporate Npm proxy)

Same mistake on our dev posts or our Jenkins docker CI-CD (Debian 9)
The issue is the same with our Nexus proxy or our private registry Artifactory

Also no problem with our code branch stayed in Jhipster v4

Yarn closed ticket did not help us : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3354

And the way around that I found is to use the ***--update-checksums*** flag on every Yarn commands

```
yarn install --update-checksums
```

and with Maven [frontend-maven-plugin eirslett](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) in the ***pom.xml*** :

```
<goals>
  <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
  <goal>yarn</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
   <arguments>install --update-checksums</arguments>
</configuration>
```

I would be happy to receive any help or explanations :)

**UPDATE:**

Return to normal with Yarn **v1.9.4** :)

Comment: Have you tried replacing yarn by npm? Also there are some issues with yarn 1.7.0, JHipster rollbacked to 1.6.0,check which version is configured in your project.

Comment: I also made a rollback on Yarn 1.6.0 but same checksum error on some libraries.

With npm it works.
We will temporarily switch to npm.
Even if I prefer to stay on the tools and standard configuration of JHipster to avoid unpleasant surprises.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with modernizr. So I removed it from package.json, then did:

```
yarn install
```

and then

```
yarn add modernizr
```

So the idea basically to remove wrong package, and then add it after installation.